# SentryOne timestamp out of sync

Tags: monitoring

We are using SentryOne to monitor the servers and noticed something very peculiar. When looking at the same server data but with SentryOne software running in different timezone, the data seems to be shifted and out of sync. I was wondering if this is due to some setting somewhere but couldn't find anything. Anyone know how to fix this.. or if this is a bug?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a better question for Sentry One support.

Comment: You are better off opening a support ticket with them .. they are quite responsive. Else @aaronbertrand might come across and help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SentryOne database stores data in UTC. When a user views data through the client, display the data from the S1 database, adjusted for the user's time zone. We don't really expect users to be able to do time zone conversions in their heads as they are reading charts, so if something happened at midnight their time, we show them that it happened at midnight their time instead of whatever UTC happened to be at that point.

So, I would expect users in different time zones to see different timestamps associated with events. For each of them that was n hours ago, but because the clock on their wall says different things now, they also said different things n hours ago when those events happened.

If you want users to see the same time for events regardless of time zone, you'll have to do the same kind of thing you have to do for Outlook meetings across an international team - run in UTC (or a specific time zone) instead of local time zone, or create a VM that does that. I don't know of a way to tell Outlook to show you calendar data in a time zone other than your own.

For future reference, we have an active and responsive support forum of our own; it is probably a quicker and more on-topic path to the answers you want about our software:

- [SentryOne Support](https://support.sentryone.com/s/)

Comment: Thank you very much.. that makes a lot of sense.